# Alternative to multiple instances of pseudo-singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I stumbled upon a pseudo-singleton class that is responsible for housing a few collections. It looks something like this:

```
public class PseudoSingleton {
    private List<Object> collection1;
    private List<Object> collection2;
    private static PseudoSingleton instance = null;

    public static synchronized PseudoSingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new PseudoSingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static synchronized void reload()  {
        instance = new PseudoSingleton();
    }

    private PseudoSingleton() {
        load();
    }
    
    private void load() {
        //parse some files from disk and fill collections
    }
}
```

The reason it is coded like this is that in a few places in code a comparison of `collection1` before and after reload needs to be done.

However this way seems like a major code smell to me.

I tried to refactor the code slightly by making the `reload()` method not static:

```
public synchronized void reload() {
   //clear collections
   //load collections
}
```

In order to be able to compare collection before reload I added a method that needs to be called before reloading the collection:

```
public List<Object> getCollection1Copy() {
   return new LinkedList<>(collection1);
}
```

However, in review I got a comment that the previous way was better and I should leave it as is. I am not convinced. Should I insist to go my way or leave it? Or is there a better way to code it?

Comment: When you generalize your code for a question, then you should do that with all your code, or else you end up with variables like `clus` which has no reference anywhere in the question. Also, is this code used to check if a file has been changed and got more entries/items? If yes, then both approaches are kinda smelly.

Comment: Sorry for the non-general code - oversight on my part, edited it. Basically yes, it is checked if after reload the collection contains modified/new objects compared to before (which are created by parsing files in folder)

Comment: I don't see the problem with it, as long as it's not pretending to be a true singleton.

Comment: When that's what you're after, then you could also use existing tools to "listen" to file changes. Then you don't need to reload the file and check the collection. For example Apache File Monitor or JDK WatchService